# Is there any performance difference between StringBuilder.append and assigning value to StringBuilder in java

Tags: java, performance

I have a `StringBuilder a`.  I have to append `a`'s content to `StringBuilder b`. If `b` is *`null`*, then assign `b=a`, otherwise `b.append(a.toString())`.

Is there any performance difference on checking if the `StringBuilder` is *`null`* or not?

```
method_a(StringBuilder a, StringBuilder b) {
    if (b != null) {
        b.append(a.toString();
    } else {
        b=a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly and highlight it as code.

Comment: "b = a" simply doesn't work, the changes in only visible within you own method, it does nothing to the outside codes which holing the ref to a and b

Comment: how can you be worried about performance when the two do different things (unless the first StringBuilder was empty)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b = a;` will have higher performance, since it's just assigning a reference.  `b.append` is a method call, and requires copying characters, and (potentially) creating a new character array.

The question is whether that's what you want.  Note that `a` and `b` are both local variables, so if you do `b = a`, you can use `b` until the end of the method.  However, it will not affect the caller.

In contrast, `b.append` modifies the object in-place.  No new object is created, so this mutation is visible outside the method.

Comment: I did not get `In contrast, b.append modifies the object in-place. No new object is created, so this mutation is visible outside the method` . It's still a local variable right ? So it cannot be referenced outside the scope of the callee and hence would not be visible

Comment: @darkie15: The StringBuilders are created outside of the method and passed in. So the outside will see what happens to them (in the append case).

Comment: @Thilo: Aahh got it. Missed out the parameters.